# Please tell me the icon shown below for samsung s8 plus?

Tags: app-icons

[image]

I just wanna know what icon shown below?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the icon of the FilmoraGo App.

[FilmoraGo - Video Editor, Video Maker For YouTube](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wondershare.filmorago&hl=en_US&gl=US)